# React-Native GoogleSignin.SIGN_IN_CANCELLED

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication, expo, google-signin

I working with react-native firebase sign in with Google from this package here:

```
https://github.com/react-native-google-signin/google-signin#project-setup-and-initialization
```

using: `yarn add @react-native-google-signin/google-signin`

It works perfectly on Android logging me in as desired however it is not working at all on iOS and have come accross the following error

```
ERROR TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'RNGoogleSignin.SIGN_IN_CANCELLED')
```

I cannot understand why this is happening on iOS but not android:

process:

```
1. yarn add @react-native-google-signin/google-signin
2. cd ios
3. pod install

- I have updated the GoogleService-Info.plist
- I have the enabled "sign in with Apple"
- The URL types have been update with reverse ID
```

Any help is welcome!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just managed to solve this issue by changing the package number from

```
"@react-native-google-signin/google-signin": "^8.0.0",
```

to this:

```
"@react-native-google-signin/google-signin": "7.2.2",
```

hope this helps anyone who needs it!

Comment: npm install @react-native-google-signin/google-signin@7.2.2

Answer (score 0):

@react-native-google-signin/google-signin does not work in expo (expo start). It works in emulator or device (npx react-native start).